# How to pass a void function as a parameter c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, function-pointers, function-call

I am trying to pass a function as a parameter.
Here, I created a function `sortingRunTime()` that takes an array and a function as a parameter and prints out the execution time.

```
void sortingRunTime(int* arr, void(*functiontocall)(int* arr))
{
    clock_t t = clock();
    (*functiontocall)(arr);
    t = clock() - t;
    cout << (t / (float)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

I have another function  `void bubblesort(int* arr)`, that sorts the array and doesn't return anything. Also, I have other sorting functions with the type of void and I have to use `sortingRunTime()` for all of the sorting functions. In the main function, I have

```
sortingRunTime(arr, bubblesort(arr));
```

but it gives an error message "argument of type "void" is incompatible with parameter of type "void (*)(int *arr)"". How can I fix it?

Comment: As written, you're actually _calling_ bubblesort.  What you want to do instead is pass the function pointer like this: `sortingRunTime(arr, bubblesort)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the function itself not the result of the function call.

So instead of

```
sortingRunTime(arr, bubblesort(arr));
```

that actually evaluates to the call

```
sortingRunTime(arr, void);
```

that is incorrect and does not make a sense you need to write

```
sortingRunTime(arr, bubblesort);
```

And within the function `sortingRunTime` it is simpler to call the function like

```
functiontocall(arr);
```

Pay attention to that these function declarations

```
void sortingRunTime(int*, void(*functiontocall)(int* ));
```

and

```
void sortingRunTime(int*, void functiontocall(int * ) );
```

are equivalent and declare the same one function.

To make the difference between thsese calls

```
sortingRunTime(arr, bubblesort(arr));
```

and

```
sortingRunTime(arr, bubblesort);
```

more visible consider the following demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <type_traits>

void bubblesort( int * );

int main() 
{
    int a[10];
    
    std::cout << std::boolalpha 
              << std::is_same<void, decltype( bubblesort( a ) )>::value 
              << '\n';
              
    std::cout << std::boolalpha 
              << std::is_same<void( int * ), decltype( bubblesort )>::value 
              << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
true
true
```

As it is seen the type of the expression `bubblesort( a )` is `void` while the type of the expression `bubblesort` is the function type `void( int * )`. This expression (function designator) used as a function argument is implicitly converted to a pointer to the function of the type `void ( * )( int * )`.

Comment: thank you, it worked. I am still learning how to use pointers, I will pay attention to the tips you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you call a function that returns void, the result of the function call is void, and you cannot pass that void as an argument into `sortingRunTime`.

`sortingRunTime` expects a (pointer to) a function as the argument. So, instead of passing the result of the function call, pass the (pointer to the) function itself:

```
sortingRunTime(arr, &bubblesort);
```

Since function implicitly converts to a pointer to itself, the use of addressof operator is optional. It works the same without it:

```
sortingRunTime(arr, bubblesort);
```